# setTimeout in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to implement zoom behaviour in D3.js, by following this [block](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/f48fcdb929a620ed97877e4678ab15e6).

There's this piece of code in the block, which I don't understand. I know how `setTimeout` behaves, but not sure how and why it's used like this, and how it fits in with the rest of the code.

I have tried debugging and going through each breakpoint meticulously, but I don't understand it's big-picture purpose or what's happening at each stage.

```
function brushended() {
  var s = d3.event.selection;
  if (!s) {
    if (!idleTimeout) return idleTimeout = setTimeout(idled, idleDelay);
    x.domain(x0);
    y.domain(y0);
  } else {
    x.domain([s[0][0], s[1][0]].map(x.invert, x));
    y.domain([s[1][1], s[0][1]].map(y.invert, y));
    svg.select(".brush").call(brush.move, null);
  }
  zoom();
}

function idled() {
  idleTimeout = null;
}
```

Not sure if this type of questions(explaining a piece of code) are appropriate for stack overflow, but I really want to understand what's happening here, instead of just copy pasting the solution. If anyone can explain this, that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Glad you asked this. I was exactly in the same boat. Now finally I think I have some understanding from the response below. I wish Mike Bostock's code were better commented.

Answer (score 1):

I think the purpose of the idle timeout section is set to zoom back to the original view when the user double clicks but moves the cursor a tiny bit between the clicks. i.e. When the clicks are `idleDelay` apart, instead of zooming in, it zooms out. 
You may find it clearer to understand by adding two console log statements I have shown below, while stepping through the code. Try double clicking and then moving the cursor a bit during clicks.

```
function brushended() {
  var s = d3.event.selection;
  if (!s) {
    if (!idleTimeout) return idleTimeout = setTimeout(idled, idleDelay);
    x.domain(x0);
    y.domain(y0);
  } else {
    console.log('zoom set')
    x.domain([s[0][0], s[1][0]].map(x.invert, x));
    y.domain([s[1][1], s[0][1]].map(y.invert, y));
    svg.select(".brush").call(brush.move, null);
  }
  zoom();
}

function idled() {
    console.log('idled')
    idleTimeout = null;
}
```